# deobfuscate Dexgaurd obfuscated code

Tags: android, obfuscation, deobfuscation, apk

I was reversing an `apk`. the `code` detects whether the `apk` is running on a rooted device or not. if it is rooted or an emulator it will stop and close out. so this is the snippet code which I think it was obfuscated with DexGuard not really sure if it is.

```
v0_4 = (int)(((Integer)((Class)withOrigin.read(((char)(-1 - Long.compare(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(0, 0), 0L))), 476 - View.combineMeasuredStates(0, 0), 18 - Long.compare(Process.getElapsedCpuTime(), 0L))).getMethod("RemoteActionCompatParcelizer", Context.class, Integer.TYPE).invoke(null, v0_3, ((int)1))));
```

so the method `RemoteActionCompatParcelizer` is the method determining whether rooted or not I believe. as such the `withOrigin.read` intercepted with `frida` returns `o.a` so tried to with jadx-gui find the package `o.a` as the method `RemoteActionCompatParcelizer` is apparently defined in this package but not found in the tree o and there are a bunch of other classes in it.

so what next steps can I take to solve these obfuscations?